# Inverse of a certain differential operator (resolvent)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, differential-operators

I am doing a research on a certain type of operator, and in the course of it I need to determine the following: Given the operator $D$ below, and identity operator $I$,
$$
        D=\begin{pmatrix}
        0 & -\text{div}\,A \\
        \nabla & 0 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $A$ is a certain operator which is not important here, can I get an explicit expression for its resolvent $(\lambda I- D)^{-1}$  ?

Thank you.

Comment: What space is everything acting on here? In particular, what is $\nabla$, what sort of operator is $A$, and how are you taking the divergence of $A$?